# Using a bit mask to store unrelated bit columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm designing a table. There are several bit columns that are unrelated to each other.

I'm considering just merging these columns together into a generic ATTRIBUTES INT bit mask column.

Now, I'm trying to convince myself that this is a bad idea. It seems like an anti-pattern. It might save me some time if I need another bit column later down the line, but are there really any benefits beyond that?

If I have an index on a bit mask, and I'm searching by ATTRIBUTES & 128 = 128, then I suspect that it's not efficient. The index would have everything ordered by the whole value, rather than by the bits. So, I imagine it would actually have to just scan the entire index instead of knowing exactly where to go.

Does that sound right? Is this a horrible idea?

Thanks,
Tedderz

Comment: That's a good rundown of the cons. What are the pros, in your mind?

Comment: personally I would keep them separate. It does take a bit more time to set things, but this way it is much easier for other people to learn your database in the future. That's the only major difference to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Not having to update all my schema scripts, sprocs, and business objects the next time I needed to add another column was the only real benefit I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a bitmask column makes

- the code harder to read and maintain
- index use impossible

It also violates the normal forms of database design.

You are not buying space either as SQL Server can compress multiple bit columns into a single byte.

However, as bit columns naturally aren't very selective, index use might not be advantageous here either.

Overall the benefits of single bit columns clearly outweigh the benefit of a bitmask column. So I would go with single bit columns in almost all cases.

Comment: You could index computed columns (which of course also negates the advantage).